# How can one calculate the force and time of impact?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

How does one calculate the force and time of impact of a body colliding into a stationery body please? Can one use Newton's 2nd law of motion?

Comment: That is not possible to do with just Newton's second law, because we neither know the time taken in the entire change in velocity, or the value of force. Atleast the total time taken is needed to calculate the average force, and the average force (or the force as a function of some known quantity like displacement of point of contact) must be known to calculate the time taken.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to calculate force and time of impact from Newton's Laws, only the change in momentum. which equals impulse, which equals the integral of force wrt time.  If the objects are very hard the time of impact will be short and the maximum force high.  If the bodies are soft or elastic the time of impact will be relatively long and the maximum force small.  To calculate how the force between the bodies varies with time you would need to know in some detail about their elasticity.

Answer (score 0):

A resultant force causes acceleration and a change in the velocity of the body for as long as it acts. A resultant force applied over a longer time therefore produces a bigger change in linear momentum than the same force applied briefly: the change in momentum is equal to the product of the average force and duration. Conversely, a small force applied for a long time produces the same change in momentum—the same **impulse**—as a larger force applied briefly.

And, Force equals to mass the acceleration , $$F=ma$$

From Newton's second law, force is related to momentum p by

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}$$
Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
 \mathbf{J} &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}\, dt \\
 &= \int_{p_1}^{p_2} d\mathbf{p} \\
 &= \mathbf{p_2} - \mathbf{p_1} = \Delta \mathbf{p} \end{align}$$

So, this means, 
$$\mathbf{J} = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathbf{F}\, dt =  \Delta\mathbf{p} = m \mathbf{v_2} - m \mathbf{v_1}$$
where,

$\Delta\mathbf{p}$ is the change in linear momentum between the change in time.

**J** is impluse.
In classical mechanics, impulse is the integral of a force, F, over the time interval, t, for which it acts.

**F** is resultant force applied

**t1 and t2** are times when the impulse begins and ends, respectively,

**m** is the mass of the object,

**v2** is the final velocity of the object at the end of the time interval,
 and

**v1** is the initial velocity of the object when the time interval begins.

Most of time I like to answer a question completely, but, I encourage one to research on their own. So, I going to provide you the base.

**Resources for study:**

- [Khanacademy videos on Impluse and linear momentum](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/linear-momentum)
- [Impluse on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics))
- [Newton's laws of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)

Want to ask anything, add a comment.